# javascript - Convert a image(or bitmap) into a two dimensional matrix

Tags: javascript, image-processing, pixel

I have an image that is initially invisible. When the user hovers his mouse over the image, I want the image to do some sorta animation.

I want to be able to take the pixels within that image and have them display in a certain order.

To do that, I was wondering if there was anyway to take the pixels of a image and put them into a two-dimensional array or some data structure to where I can set an individual pixel to visible or invisible.......if that's possible.

FYI this is the first time I've REALLY developed in javascript, so there may be some common sense javascript stuff that I'm not aware of.

Comment: [Pixel manipulation with canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas)

Answer (score 3):

That's possible. Just use the canvas element, put an image on it by using the drawImage method and then you can directly manipulate pixel data in your canvas at the byte level just by using ImageData with combination of CanvasPixelArray